# Is there an easy way to find the 'coordinates' of an element in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe 'ptable' which looks like this:

[image: A 188 x 32 dataframe of the periodic table containing varying types of data.]

We were given a very easy task of finding one value in the dataframe, the boiling point of argon. Their sample solution was to simply do this (this is a very basic course in computer science for chemists):

```
print(ptable.loc[17, 'BoilingPoint'])
```

This isn't a very good solution in my opinion as it requires knowing the index of the value you're looking up (in this case simple since it is just the atomic number minus one but may be more tedious in future.

I tried to write a quick function to try to make this more future-proof, or to work on similar dataframes:

```
def element_data(element, property):
    row = (ptable.index[ptable['Element'] == element])[0]
    #column = ptable.columns.get_loc(property)
    print(ptable.loc[row, property])
element_data('Argon', 'BoilingPoint')
```

This works fine but would only work on this specific dataframe, and I'm not happy with the implementation for finding the index of the row as it looks very inelegant. I'd also like to know if there is a pandas function whereby I can use the commented out 'column' variable.

The ideal function would be able to take the element as either atomic number, name or symbol, and produce any property asked.

Is there a better way to approach this problem such that intimate knowledge of the dataframe's structure is not needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```py
import pandas as pd

def locate(data, query, value, output):
    df = pd.DataFrame(data = data)
    # create a list of values in the query (column)
    values = df[query].tolist()
    row = 0
    if value in values:
        row = values.index(value)
    return df.loc[row, output]
```

Where the input data looks like this:

```py
d = {
    'AtomicNumber': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'Element': ['Hydrogen', 'Helium', 'Lithium', 'Beryllium', 'Boron'],
    'Symbol': ['H', 'He', 'Li', 'Be', 'B'],
    'BoilingPoint': [20.28, 4.22, 1615.00, 2742.00, 4200.00],
}

value = locate(data=d, query='Symbol', value='He', output='BoilingPoint')
```

Ouput:

```
4.22
```

The query is basically the column in which the value you pass in falls. For example, I specified the query as "Symbol" and then passed in a value ("He") that falls under that query. The output is simply what data type you want the output to be. I want the boiling point of He, so I passed in "BoilingPoint" as the output parameter.

Of course, you could also call the function like this, without explicitly writing the parameters.

```
locate(d, 'Symbol', 'He', 'BoilingPoint')
```

However, due to the fact that all of the parameters are similar to one another, readability improves if you explicitly set each parameter.

Comment: I don't think I could ask for a better solution! Thank you very much, I'll comment the code a bit more but you answered all of my questions implicitly in the code! I can't +1 due to <15 rep but I'm very grateful!

Comment: No problem! Can you accept the answer by selecting the checkmark underneath of the upvote/downvote? Other users may not know that your problem was solved. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think [gmdev solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64102895/14277722) is much nicer, but I want to point out that there is a [`pandas.query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) syntax for this kind of queries.

```
d = {
    'AtomicNumber': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'Element': ['Hydrogen', 'Helium', 'Lithium', 'Beryllium', 'Boron'],
    'Symbol': ['H', 'He', 'Li', 'Be', 'B'],
    'BoilingPoint': [20.28, 4.22, 1615.00, 2742.00, 4200.00],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df.query('Element == "Helium"')['BoilingPoint']
```

Out:

```
1    4.22
Name: BoilingPoint, dtype: float64
```